# How to redirect to previous view with timer?

Tags: objective-c

So I have a view that goes to another, call it view 2.

On view 2, on load, a timer should start. If the button named "signin" isn't pressed within 30 seconds it should redirect the user to the previous view (view 1).

How can I achieve this? Can't find any documentation on it.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system? How is `view2` shown (show code)?

Comment: @wain: tagged as objective-c! This isn't a desktop-based app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(goBack:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
    ...
}

- (void)goBack {
    // Pop to previous view controller or whatever.
}

- (void)didPressButton:(id)sender {
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil;
}
```